# Magento move data from product page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

help me out to tag this 3 features above add to cart button

[image: Bookstore]

Answer (score 0):

yes,can do this by some xml code.
Create a layout file **local.xml** at **app/design/frontend/default/THEME/layout** add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="product.info.addto" />
         <remove name ="product.info.sharing" /> 
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Did not get any idea to remove Text `Seller Sarika` asit manage from custom module

Answer (score 0):

Please open this file.`app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

You can modify here.